# STL pair input with STL map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, std-pair

```
map <int, string> rollCallRegister;
map <int, string> :: iterator rollCallRegisterIter;

pair <map <int, string> , bool> returnPair;

rollCallRegister.insert (pair <int, string> (1, "anisha"));
```

In this code, `pair <map <int, string> , bool> returnPair;` means that this pair takes a map row as the first value and a bool as the second.

**Question**:
*How to insert bool here: `rollCallRegister.insert (pair <int, string> (1, "anisha"));`?*

Secondly, `pair <map <int, string> :: iterator, bool> returnPair;` This pair takes an iterator of map as the first input.

**Question**:
*How is this different from the previous pair syntax, since the insertion way is still the same: `rollCallRegister.insert (pair <int, string> (1, "anisha"));`?*

Comment: It is unclear what the question is. The insert method returns iterator to the inserted key and a bool showing whether insertion occurred (or the key already existed)?

Comment: First question: What do you mean there? `rollCallRegister` doesn't have a `bool` member, only `returnPair` has. Do you want to insert `rollCallRegister` together with a `bool` into `returnPair`?

Comment: @visitor insert returns a pair, and that pair's first argument can be a map row, as well as a map iterator. But the insertion syntax of insert is the same for the both way. Why? Secondly, when we decalre the pair as `pair <map <int, string> , bool>` what does the insert return? An iterator?

Comment: @bitmask Of course, but the pair which gets inserted into map does have a bool member.

Comment: @bitmask See my last comment on Luc's answer. I had confused myself. :)

Comment: @AnishaKaul: No, the pair that is inserted into the map does **not** have a bool member, the bool is just returned by `insert` to indicate whether the insertion occurred or not, depending on whether the key was already present or not.

Comment: @LucTouraille Yeah, Yeah got it now, see my comment on your answer. thanks BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value of a `pair<map<int, string >, bool>` is *not* a map row, it is an entire map (so probably not what you are looking for). The second pair, on the other hand, associates a map entry to a boolean value.

Regarding the insertion, I don't really get your question: in both samples, you are inserting into a `map<int, string>`; it has nothing to do with the different types of pairs you define. To create instances of these two kind of pairs, you need a `map` in the first case, and an iterator in the second:

```
pair<map<string, int>, bool> p1(rollCallRegister, true);
pair<map<string, int>::iterator, bool> p2(rollCallRegisterIter, false);
```

*Edit:*

Based on the comments you made on your question, I think you confuse the content of the map (`pair<string, int>`) and the value returned by `insert` (`pair<map<string, int>::iterator, bool>`).

When you declare a `map<K,V>`, its content is stored in `pair<K,V>`. Therefore, to insert a new entry in this map, you need to create a pair containing the key and the value you want to insert:

```
map<K,V> myMap;
pair<K,V> myEntry(key, value); // entry to insert

myMap.insert(myEntry);         //or you can create the entry on-the-fly
myMap.insert(make_pair(key, value));
```

Now, when you insert an entry into a map, there is a possibility that the key was already present. If this is the case, then the insertion should "failed": after the call to `insert`, the key is still associated with the former value. However, the caller should be warned that he tried to insert an entry with a key that already existed in the map.

This is achieved by having `insert` return a `pair<map<K,V>::iterator, bool>`, where the second value of this pair is a boolean indicating whether the insertion occurred (the key was not already present in the map) or not. The first value is an iterator to the entry corresponding to the key. This entry contains the key and its associated value (either the one you just inserted, or the one that was already there).

Comment: Luc, and @visitor Oh I got now :banghead: My problem was that I was thinking that the pair I have declared like: `pair<map<string, int>::iterator, bool>` is the one that gets inserted into the map. where as the fact is that insert takes a simple pair of any two value, and returns an iterator to the row of the map and a bool value! I think I have got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't also insert a **bool** into **rollCallRegister** since it takes only a int as key and a string as value in your current form.

If you wish the **rollCallRegister** map to contain a **pair of (int, string) as key** and a **bool as value** you need to change it to:

```
map <pair<int, string>, bool> rollCallRegister;
rollCallRegister.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(yourint, yourstring), true/false));
```

Comment: What's the semantic of `map < map`? `std::map` keys must have a meaningful strict total ordering.

Comment: @bitmask: The semantic of `map<map`, as defined in the standard, is the lexicographical ordering of the pair sequence. BTW, the keys don't need a total order, but only a strict weak order.

Comment: Changed the example to use a pair as key.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused. Your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly trivial: `pair<pair <int, string>, bool>`. You might want to look into `make_pair` though.